# which tense is correct for "wish"?

Tags: tense, grammaticality

> I thought by myself I (**wish\wished**) never had I started that match.

1- In the above sentence, which tense is correct for "wish"?
2- Instead of "I thought by myself", what another sentence can I use?
3- It was said that the whole sentence is grammatically incorrect, could someone tell what is its problem?

Comment: The sentence as a whole is essentially ungrammatical. That aside, it depends entirely on when the wish is made.

Comment: @JasonBassford 1- Could you tell why the whole sentence is grammatically incorrect? 2- What if the wish is made in the past? 3- What if the wish is made in the present?

Comment: Essentially: ✘ *I thought by myself I wish[ed] never had I started that match.* ✔ *I wish[ed] I had never started that match.*

Comment: "I thought by myself" is awkward. "I thought to myself" is better, but it is probably redundant here because "I wished" is about my thoughts. "I thought to myself how much I wished I had never started the match" is possible, but emphasises the strength of the wish. If you have "thought" you would use "wished" not "wish" as their tenses need to match.